# Why are there so many wasps attached to this air conditioner?

Tags: animal-behaviour, wasps

[image]

I wish to get rid of these wasps. I am not sure what they are trying to do. Are these wasps creating a hive? Or is there something from the A/C they are collecting to create a hive somewhere else?

Comment: What kind of wasps are those? They look like flies.

Comment: Hi Vaibhav! Is the air conditioner fully attached to the wall, with no open areas at all? That's very important. Many types of these, usually honey bees, either already have or are building a hive in the wall behind the a/c unit, not on the unit. If it's tight and they're in the crevices they can be looking for the controlled temperature, and water. Let us know exactly where they are. Also, more pictures and close up views would be very helpful in identifying it, and learn about the behavior. Thanks!

Comment: This might be a better fit on https://biology.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: If that line is the cold Freon out (and it looks like it, since the insulation is thicker than the other line), then they are likely collecting water from condensate on the line. Is it dry in your area?

Comment: Yes. It is dry and hot. However, it is winter season now. I will check if I still see the wasps.

Answer (score 1):

They're almost certainly building a nest inside. The condenser provides them an enclosed space for their nest, as well as an ample water source from the condensate.

If you want to get rid of them, buy a wasp spray. They shoot a powerful stream so you can shoot from a distance and typically stun them. The ones inside the unit should evacuate quickly and some may even escape. I've never had them return after spraying.

It would be worth fixing the holes so they cannot return either.